# What Race Causes the Output to Look Different?

Tags: c, pipe, fork, child-process

I was given this question on a midterm last year.

> Consider the following program.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 int main (void) {
  int pid = getpid ();
  printf ("hello world (pid:%d)\n", pid);
  int rc = fork();
  if (rc < 0) {
   fprintf (stderr, "fork failed\n");
   retrun 1;
  }
  pid = getpid();
  if (rc == 0) {
   printf ("hello, I am child (pid:%d)\n", pid);
  } else {
   printf("hello, I am parent of %d (pid:%d)\n", rc, pid);
  } 
  return 0;
 }
```

> And consider the following behavior that I got when I compiled and ran this program:

```
$ gcc -02 -Wall question.c
$ ./a.out # First program run
hello world (pid:20600)
hello, I am parent of 20601 (pid:20600)
hello, I am child (pid:20601)
$ ./a.out | cat # Second program run
hello world (pid:20605)
hello, I am parent of 20607 (pid:20605)
hello world (pid:20605)
hello, I am child (pid:20607)
```

> a) What race could cause the output to look substantially different from either the first or the second run, and what would this output look like?
>
> b) Explain each different in the outputs of the two program runs.

For part (a) I argued that there is a race between the child process and the parent process, and that the child can print before the parent, but apparently that was wrong. Is there any other race that would cause the output to be different? And why is my answer wrong?

For part (b) I am shaky on multiple things. First is that I see the PIDs are different in both runs, but I don't have a good explanation for that. Second that extra hello world in the second run is because of the way the program is being run with a pipe and the cat command?

Comment: Remember that `fork` creates an exact duplicate of the parent process, including the buffers used by `stdout` (which is where `printf` writes). In the second case it seems that the buffer from the first `printf` call haven't been flushed when the process is forked.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I'm curious: stdout is not supposed to be flushed by the `\n`character at the first `printf`?

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean Thank you, that pointed me in the right direction! :)

Comment: As a side note I hope they are not the real exam questions, considering the very poor english...

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean it was :) OS course

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you pipe the output to `cat`.

By default, when `stdout` is connected to a terminal or console, then `stdout` is *line buffered* which means that the internal buffers are flushed at newline (or when the buffer is full, or when `fflush` is called).

But when `stdout` is *not* connected to a terminal or console, like when it is connected to a pipe, it becomes *fully* buffered. This means it will only be flushed if the buffer becomes full or `fflush` is called. Printing newlines doesn't do anything special, the newline is just added to the buffer.

Now because `stdout` is fully buffered the buffer with the contents of the first `printf` call will be copied to the child process as part of the `fork` call, and will be flushed when the child process exits.

Comment: Found this link that might be helpful: https://eklitzke.org/stdout-buffering